# Why does adding a table name to a sql column cause the query to fail?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given the following Query (which works fine with SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT [ID], [SSN] FROM Employee
```

Why does adding the table name to the columns cause an error?

```
SELECT [Employee.ID], [Employee.SSN] FROM Employee
```

> Invalid column name 'Employee.ID'. Invalid column name 'Employee.SSN'.

Can the table name only be added when there is an ambiguous column name such as in the case of a join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of your brackets. Do like this instead:

```
SELECT [Employee].[ID], [Employee].[SSN] FROM [Employee];
```

Comment: DOH! Why didn't I see that?

Answer (score 2):

You should do [employee].[id].
The table needs to be in a separate Set of square brackets than the field name